# Windows form, C#, background image

Tags: c#, image, forms, background

I'm developing a project using Windows Forms. Here I have created a form in which I used TableLayout tool and a label. I have set a background image for form. I want the same background to be set to table and label without setting background for each of them again.

Is this possible?

Comment: A screenshot with the form would be a good addition to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is go to your table layout **properties** and set the Background color to **Transparent**